# How to create reusable function that uses state and props in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refactoring, react-props, react-state

I have a function that sends data to the server and uses `props` and `set...`. It is the same throughout few components. It gets called when a certain event occurs.

How can I refactor it out of those components into a single place?

*I was thinking about using hooks but because it gets triggered by an event I don't think using a hook is a good approach.*

```
async function sendDataToServer(data) {
    const url = new URL(buildUrl());
    let timeout = setTimeout(() => setPostingState(SendingState.Sending), 250);
    try {
        const response = props.id
            ? await axios.put(url, data)
            : await axios.post(url, data);
        setPostingState(SendingState.Idle);
        props.onSaved(props.id ? props.id : response.data, data);
    }
    catch (error) {
        setPostingState(SendingState.Error);
    }
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}

function handleSubmit(e) { ... sendDataToServer(data); ... }
```

Comment: Are you using functional components? Custom hooks might be what you need.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on what the function needs to do, maybe you could implement it in a custom hook (if you are not using class based components)

Comment: Any code? You got over 15k points already, a minimal example should be obvious. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DennisVash is it good now?

Comment: How exactly you resolve this promise in an event handler? Are you asking how to extract function logic so it will generic on setter and props? How this function differ in all components? Elaborate please

Comment: @DennisVash I do not resolve it at all. I just call it, and then later it updates state and calls into the parent component to let it know that it can switch from `Edit` to `View` mode.

Comment: @DennisVash it is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a curried function:

```
// helpers.js
export const genSendDataToServerCallback = ({ setState, onSaved, id }) => async (
  data
) => {
  const url = new URL(buildUrl());
  let timeout = setTimeout(() => setState(SendingState.Sending), 250);
  try {
    const response = await (props.id
      ? axios.put(url, data)
      : axios.post(url, data));
    setState(SendingState.Idle);
    onSaved(id ? id : response.data, data);
  } catch (error) {
    setState(SendingState.Error);
  }
  clearTimeout(timeout);
};


// Usage in some component
import { genSendDataToServerCallback } from './helpers.js'

const sendDataToServer = genSendDataToServerCallback({setter:setPostingState, ...props});
function handleSubmit(e) { sendDataToServer(data); }

// Usage in other component with different setter
const sendDataToServer = genSendDataToServerCallback({setter:setState, ...props});
function handleSubmit(e) { sendDataToServer(data); }
```